# Unique row identifier in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I work on Presto SQL tables that don't have unique row identifiers. The only way to identify a specific record is to query all of its fields.

Is there in Presto some kind of hidden field, say `ROW_PRIMARY_KEY`, that would allow me to uniquely identify records in my tables?

Comment: You can add a primary key when you create the table.

Comment: Presto is a query engine that operates over existing data sources, so it can pass through this kind of data if it exists in the underlying data source, but it can't create on itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wish I was the one creating those tables...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of a primary key, you could just toss in a

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY some, columns ORDER BY some_other_column) as rn
```

This will define a row number where `some, columns` would be a psuedo-primary key.

Answer (score 6):

To extend and simplify the [answer by JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822313/), if you just want a row number:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS row_num
```

Note that `OVER ()` may function the same as `OVER (PARTITION BY 1)`, implying that all rows are assigned to the same partition. In this way, all rows will have unique row numbers.